# Using iron-router to go to a certain id section of the page (url#portion) in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have routes set up with iron-router that make sure the page goes to the top of the page:

```
Router.route('/services', {
    name: 'services',
    template: 'services',
  onAfterAction: function () {
          scrollTop();
  }  
});

function scrollTop() {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

However, if I am on another route, and I have a link like /services#thisid

it will still take me to the top of the page (not to the portion of the page with the id=thisid).

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Iron Router recognizes the fragment #thisid portion as `this.params.hash`. The [documentation](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) (search for this.params.hash) is written in the `Router.route('/route', function(){` syntax, and I don't have a test case for you, but an if statement that checks for a hash should be able to prevent the undesired scrollTop() calls.

Comment: could you please apply this to my case?  I am not getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should address your issue both for this issue and your [layout override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617620/overriding-a-layouttemplate-for-a-specific-route-with-iron-router-in-meteor-js-a?noredirect=1#comment58951916_35617620) question.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'main',
  onAfterAction: function(){
    console.log('hash', this.params.hash);
    if(!this.params.hash){
      scrollTop();
    }
  }
});
Router.route('/services', {
  name: 'services',
  template: 'services',
});

Router.route('/inquiry', {
  name: 'inquiry',
  template: 'inquiry',
  layoutTemplate: 'alternate'
});
```

The check for `this.params.hash` ensures that there is no value for the hash before executing the scrollTop. The `layoutTemplate` on the inquiry route overrides the layout while still respecting the global onAfterAction.

Comment: Error: Couldn't find a template named "alternate" or "alternate". Are you sure you defined it?

Comment: unless for layoutTemplate I just use layoutTemplate: 'inquiry'

Comment: also, the hash (#this or #that) is not taking them to that id in the page with this route system...

Comment: I misread your question as having already made that behavior work. This appears to be a [larger problem with iron:router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1171). They have a workaround there.
As to the route and template names, you can change them. Those are the names I used to test.